How to remove extra padding like width from text element in SVG?
I'm creating a <svg> with <textPath>. Code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="212 134 329 104"
      data-viewbox=""
      class=""
      style="overflow: visible;"
    >
      <g style="width: 100%;">
        <path
          id="myPath"
          d="M 240 218.833 C 258.313 204.667 291.276 185.667 299.933 185.667 C 308.923 185.667 314.584 188.833 339.889 202.333 C 365.86 216 371.853 219 380.511 219 C 389.501 219 394.828 215.5 419.8 202.167 C 446.104 188.167 452.098 185.833 459.756 185.667 C 471.742 185.667 477.736 191.333 500.71 202.167 C 515.694 209.333 530.344 215 540 218.667"
          stroke=""
          fill="none"
          stroke-width="1"
        ></path>
        <text dx="0" dy="0">
          <textPath href="#myPath">Hello world</textPath>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>



Output:

The <text> element is taking extra width (skyblue portion), but it should take only the width marked by the red line. How to achieve that?

Edit the font so there are no ascenders or descenders i.e. the letter y (has a descender) and those extra tall l's are a problem too. I.e. this isn't really going to be feasible.

You can't get a tight bounding box for text elements (same applies to HTML text). You may try to render the textPath to a canvas and find the visual tight bounding box by checking transparency. See: "Cropping an HTML canvas to the width/height of its visible pixels (content)?".

I'm Shobana

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SVG TextPath Example</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        svg {
            background-color: lightblue;
            border: 2px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="400" height="250"
      viewBox="0 0 400 250"
      style="overflow: visible;"
    >
      <path
          id="myPath"
          d="M 50 150 C 150 50, 250 50, 350 150"
          fill="none"
          stroke="none"
      ></path>
      <text font-size="48" fill="darkslategray" font-family="serif">
          <textPath href="#myPath" startOffset="10%">
            Hello world
          </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>


Sorry but you answer doesn't remove any padding around the path as asked by the OP. Besides, please add some description to explain your approach.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
